# some error while running spring mvc project

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, build

Springsource tool suite is the tool am using.

these are the errors..

```
>     Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>     Error occured processing XML 'Unable to load schema mappings from location [META-INF/spring.schemas]'. See Error Log for more
> details   root-context.xml    /masterdataqa/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring    Unknown Spring
> Beans Problem
```

and

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type Error occured processing XML
>   'Unable to load schema mappings from location
>   [META-INF/spring.schemas]'. See Error Log for more
>   details   servlet-context.xml /masterdataqa/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet Unknown Spring
>   Beans Problem
>
> Apr 24, 2012 10:44:31 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener
>   init INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows
>   optimal performance in production environments was not found on the
>   java.library.path: C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin;C:\Program Files\IBM\Lotus\Notes;C:\Program
>   Files\PHP;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\DMIX;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program
>   Files\PHP;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program
>   Files\Heroku\bin;C:\Program Files\ruby-1.9.3\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\git\bin;C:\Program Files\git\cmd;D:\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin;;.
>   Apr 24, 2012 10:44:32 AM
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin WARNING:
>   [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting
>   property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:masterdataqa' did not
>   find a matching property. Apr 24, 2012 10:44:34 AM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO: Initializing
>   ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"] Apr 24, 2012 10:44:34 AM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO: Initializing
>   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"] Apr 24, 2012 10:44:34 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load INFO: Initialization
>   processed in 4747 ms Apr 24, 2012 10:44:34 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal INFO: Starting
>   service Catalina Apr 24, 2012 10:44:34 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal INFO: Starting
>   Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.25 Apr 24, 2012 10:44:35 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom INFO:
>   Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using
>   [SHA1PRNG] took [140] milliseconds. Apr 24, 2012 10:44:36 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile INFO:
>   validateJarFile(C:\Documents and
>   Settings\srinivasa\Documents\workspace-sts-2.9.0.RELEASE.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\masterdataqa\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api.jar)
>   - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class Apr 24, 2012 10:44:36 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body INFO: TLD skipped. URI:
>   http://www.springframework.org/tags/form is already defined Apr 24,
>   2012 10:44:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body INFO:
>   TLD skipped. URI: http://www.springframework.org/tags is already
>   defined Apr 24, 2012 10:44:36 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body INFO: TLD skipped. URI:
>   http://www.springframework.org/tags/form is already defined Apr 24,
>   2012 10:44:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body INFO:
>   TLD skipped. URI: http://www.springframework.org/tags is already
>   defined Apr 24, 2012 10:44:37 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: Initializing
>   Spring root WebApplicationContext INFO :
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root
>   WebApplicationContext: initialization started INFO :
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext -
>   Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Apr 24
>   10:44:37 IST 2012]; root of context hierarchy INFO :
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader -
>   Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml] ERROR:
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization
>   failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load schema mappings from
>   location [META-INF/spring.schemas]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:412)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:93)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:397)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1568)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1558)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load schema mappings from
>   location [META-INF/spring.schemas]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver.getSchemaMappings(PluggableSchemaResolver.java:153)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver.resolveEntity(PluggableSchemaResolver.java:110)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DelegatingEntityResolver.resolveEntity(DelegatingEntityResolver.java:85)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.ResourceEntityResolver.resolveEntity(ResourceEntityResolver.java:74)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.EntityResolverWrapper.resolveEntity(EntityResolverWrapper.java:107)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.resolveEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1100)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.resolveDocument(XMLSchemaLoader.java:595)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2432)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1782)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:705)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:400)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:626)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3104)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:922)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:235)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:284)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
>     ... 23 more Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header
>   (bad signature)   at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)    at
>   java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1200(ZipFile.java:31)    at
>   java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:459)   at
>   java.util.zip.ZipFile$1.fill(ZipFile.java:242)    at
>   java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:141)
>     at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:116)   at
>   java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:90)     at
>   java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:418)     at
>   java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:337)   at
>   java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:325)    at
>   org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadAllProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:111)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver.getSchemaMappings(PluggableSchemaResolver.java:144)
>     ... 46 more Apr 24, 2012 10:44:37 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart SEVERE:
>   Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of
>   class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load schema mappings from
>   location [META-INF/spring.schemas]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:412)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:93)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:397)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1568)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1558)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load schema mappings from
>   location [META-INF/spring.schemas]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver.getSchemaMappings(PluggableSchemaResolver.java:153)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver.resolveEntity(PluggableSchemaResolver.java:110)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DelegatingEntityResolver.resolveEntity(DelegatingEntityResolver.java:85)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.ResourceEntityResolver.resolveEntity(ResourceEntityResolver.java:74)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.EntityResolverWrapper.resolveEntity(EntityResolverWrapper.java:107)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.resolveEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1100)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.resolveDocument(XMLSchemaLoader.java:595)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2432)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1782)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:705)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:400)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:626)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3104)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:922)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:235)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:284)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
>     ... 23 more Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header
>   (bad signature)   at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)    at
>   java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1200(ZipFile.java:31)    at
>   java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:459)   at
>   java.util.zip.ZipFile$1.fill(ZipFile.java:242)    at
>   java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:141)
>     at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:116)   at
>   java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:90)     at
>   java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:418)     at
>   java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:337)   at
>   java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:325)    at
>   org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadAllProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:111)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver.getSchemaMappings(PluggableSchemaResolver.java:144)
>     ... 46 more Apr 24, 2012 10:44:37 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal SEVERE: Error
>   listenerStart Apr 24, 2012 10:44:37 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal SEVERE: Context
>   [/masterdataqa] startup failed due to previous errors Apr 24, 2012
>   10:44:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO:
>   Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext Apr 24, 2012 10:44:37 AM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFO: Starting
>   ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"] Apr 24, 2012 10:44:37 AM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFO: Starting
>   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"] Apr 24, 2012 10:44:37 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start INFO: Server startup in
>   2790 ms

Comment: Revelant part seems to be `Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature) at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)` some bad zip (perhaps jar)  file

Comment: sir..thanks for your responce..should i remove it?? please help me sir

Comment: I think you need to post revelant part of your spring configuration

Comment: but the same project is working fine in my friends machine sir..i dont knaow whats the problem was..please help sir

Comment: SpringSource Tool Suite 

Version: 2.9.1.RELEASE
Build Id: 201203221000

Comment: sir am not using any zip file

Comment: jar == zip. I would "redownload" everything from your friend machine. or check everything with some kind of CRC

Comment: sir am using his project only....but the same is not working in my machine

Comment: Like @RC. said, it looks like you may have a corrupted spring jar. If you are using maven, I suggest you clear your local maven repository and do a fresh `mvn clean install`. If you are not using maven, you could try replacing your spring jars (start with spring-context.jar) with freshly downloaded ones.

Answer (score 10):

This means the jar files in your project class path are corrupt. Just delete the jar files and download them again.

If you are using Maven:

```
#delete repository
rm -rf ~/.m2/repository/*

#use maven
mvn test
```

This will delete all files in **~/.m2/repository/** first and then, `mvn test` will download all dependent jar files before building your project and running junit tests.

Read more here: [Maven:: Invalid CEN (bad signature) Invalid LOC (bad signature)](https://deepumohan.com/tech/maven-invalid-cen-bad-signature-invalid-loc/)

Comment: Very anoying issue... I spent 20 mins scratching my head. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I fixed it changing my maven path of settings.xml in STS, it was on .m2 (in my user directory) and changed it for maven installation directory/conf/settings.xml

The .m2 directory, was shared with Netbeans and other version of STS, when I create my first Spring MVC project with the newest version of STS, it doesn't work because of this. I suppose that Netbeans and the older version of STS did some kind of their configuration over this folder or installed some software that does not work with the new version of STS-Spring MVC project template.

Answer (score 0):

see the error logs in eclipse, delete the corrupt jar folder and let maven install it again. This should solve the problem.