# spring error during build

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc

I have to make small website using `spring`. so i chose `spring template project` then `new spring mvc project` whatever i try **there is an error that occurred**

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'mTime'.Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'mTime'.
Could not calculate build plan: Failed to parse plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1 (C:\Users\User01\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-war-plugin\2.1.1\maven-war-plugin-2.1.1.jar): invalid LOC header (bad signature)
Failed to parse plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1 (C:\Users\User01\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-war-plugin\2.1.1\maven-war-plugin-2.1.1.jar): invalid LOC header (bad signature)
Could not calculate build plan: Failed to parse plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1 (C:\Users\User01\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-war-plugin\2.1.1\maven-war-plugin-2.1.1.jar): invalid LOC header (bad signature)
Failed to parse plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1 (C:\Users\User01\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-war-plugin\2.1.1\maven-war-plugin-2.1.1.jar): invalid LOC header (bad signature)
```

i know that `maven` is included in `spring framework`, and when i check the directory, the jars are there.

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The relevant part of the error message is:

```
invalid LOC header (bad signature)
```

which suggests some binary file being broken, most likely one of the dependencies. If you have a fast Internet connection, just delete your whole maven repository and let maven redownload all the dependencies:

```
rm -rf ~/.m2/repository/*
```

## See also

- [some error while running spring mvc project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292103)
- [*Maven:: Invalid CEN (bad signature) Invalid LOC (bad signature)*](http://tech.deepumohan.com/2012/07/maven-invalid-cen-bad-signature-invalid.html)

Comment: Never had this happen before, but this was most certainly the answer.

Comment: Or you can delete broken binary, from local maven repo. Instead of waiting for whole dependencies to be downloaded again.

Comment: Yes @MohanMahajan is right. We should go to the m2 folder find the location of our binary and delete it. Then run mvn command.

Answer (score 26):

From my experience , `invalid LOC header (bad signature)` is most probably due to the downloaded .jar file is corrupt.

If you have a slow internet connection , instead of deleting the whole Maven repository  ,  you can try to delete the folder containing the problematic jar according to the hints of the errors message (i.e `C:\Users\User01\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-war-plugin\2.1.1\`) . Then use `mvn clean install -U` to download the dependencies again.

Comment: o.k. in principle - can be semi-automated with a script solution (see Answer of Oct 2013

Comment: For me just deleting the directory fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3):

for me running the following script multiple times worked. It looks for CEN and LOC header line
issues in the mvn result and asks for deleting the jars one by one. After a few deletions and reruns things should be working again. I didn't dare to fully automate.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# fix issues like:
#[ERROR] error: error reading /Users/wf/.m2/repository/org/docx4j/xhtmlrenderer/1.0.0/xhtmlrenderer-1.0.0.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
# WF 2013-10-27
mvnlog=/tmp/mvnlog$$
mvnproblem=/tmp/mvnproblem$$
mvn install | tee $mvnlog
grep "invalid ... header" $mvnlog > $mvnproblem
for culprit in `cat $mvnproblem | cut -d" " -f5  | cut -d ";" -f1`
do
  echo "fix mvn LOC header issue with $culprit? yes/no/abort"
    read answer
    case $answer in
      y*|Y*) rm $culprit;;
        n*|N*) ;;
        *) exit 1;
    esac
done
rm -f $mvnproblem
rm -f $mvnlog
```

Answer (score 3):

It Throw Because your .jar is Invalid Or Corrupted.

Follow the Steps:

Note : .m2 Folder is Hidden by Default. UnHide the Folder.

Step 1:Delete all the Content in .m2/repository Folder.

Step 2:Restart Your Eclipse.

Step 3:Maven->Update Project .Checked- Force Update of Snapshots/Releases.

Step 4:Run as Maven Clean.

Step 5:Run as Maven Install.

Step 6: Clean Project.

Step 7 : Run Your Project.

I Hope you Find your Solution Here..

Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

add debug output when running maven. It will show you which jar is broken. Delete just that one.

Comment: o.k in principle - see script solution

Answer (score 1):

Another solution for finding the culprit when getting this error starting Tomcat on Windows or when you can't run Wolfgang's script is to replace JarResourceSet.class in catalina.jar with a version that has extra debugging.

Ie google for the source code for your version of Tomcat and adapt the initInternal() method :

```
    String processingJar = "";

    try (JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(getBase())) {
        processingJar = jarFile.getName();

        ...
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Failed with " + processingJar);
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(ioe);
    }
```

To build, your classpath should point to your Tomcat lib directory eg :

```
javac -cp C:\apache-tomcat-X.Y.Z\lib\* JarResourceSet.java
```

Then use 7zip or similar program to insert it into catalina.jar in the appropriate directory and run Tomcat.  I was astonished that it worked first time but it did.  (Then you just need to find where in your .m2 repository the offending jar file is and delete and rebuild etc.)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to completely remove your local maven repository, use the following to find the broken artifacts and remove them:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    findBrokenZip(Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/.m2/repository"));
}

static void findBrokenZip(Path path) throws IOException {
    try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(path)) {
        for (Path entry : stream) {
            if (Files.isDirectory(entry)) {
                findBrokenZip(entry);
            } else {
                if (entry.getFileName().toString().endsWith(".jar")) {
                    try (JarFile zipFile = new JarFile(entry.toFile())) {
                        zipFile.getManifest();
                    } catch (ZipException e) {
                        Files.delete(entry);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Help -> Install New Softwares
```

From there install the bundle with Web developments, XML, CSS, Java EE ...
And after that if this built problem still continue, please use the command

```
rm -rf ~/.m2/repository/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
find ~/.m2  -name "*.lastUpdated" -exec grep -q "Could not transfer" {} \; -print -exec rm {} \;
```