# showing error on pom.xml while building spring application on STS

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, maven

This is the error I get when I was trying to create my first spring application in STS

```
Error during build of project [SpringDemo]
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'SpringDemo'.
Could not calculate build plan: Failed to parse plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1 (C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-war-plugin\2.1.1\maven-war-plugin-2.1.1.jar): invalid LOC header (bad signature)
Failed to parse plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1 (C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-war-plugin\2.1.1\maven-war-plugin-2.1.1.jar): invalid LOC header (bad signature)
Could not calculate build plan: Failed to parse plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1 (C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-war-plugin\2.1.1\maven-war-plugin-2.1.1.jar): invalid LOC header (bad signature)
Failed to parse plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1 (C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-war-plugin\2.1.1\maven-war-plugin-2.1.1.jar): invalid LOC header (bad signature)
```

Have error in pom.xml..

Please help i'm new in Spring...

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with Spring.

Comment: then anything with maven?

Comment: Google for `invalid LOC header (bad signature)`.

Comment: Looks like some of your libraries (e.g maven-war-plugin) are corrupted. Try deleting these libraries from your local m2 repo and build online!

Comment: thanks @ its fine after deleting maven repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

binary file being broken, most likely one of the dependencies.just delete your whole maven repository and let maven redownload all the dependencies:

delete C:\Users\user.m2\repository

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13044692/2334391
http://tech.deepumohan.com/2012/07/maven-invalid-cen-bad-signature-invalid.html

Comment: do you have any sample project for spring 4

Comment: if you are a beginner i sugest you to not to go with sample project. Go with some tutorial build the project by yourself(environment) then it would be easy for you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your `.m2` folder and then fire the `mvn install` command.

> Invalid LOC header

This issue is related to some bad jar present in the m2 folder that got corrupted during download