# Embedded Jetty JSP example stops working when jetty 9.2 is replaced by 9.3 in pom

Tags: java, maven, jsp, jetty

I am fluent in Java, but only average in web technology. Now, I am looking into using Jetty in a project. I am using Eclipse Neon for Java SE. To familiarize myself with Jetty, I have implemented the embedded jetty jsp example from https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jetty/jetty-jsp-example/ from August last year. It uses Jetty 9.2.11 and it works fine. See log below.

Then I want to upgrade it to the latest Jetty version, so in pom.xml I replace every occurrence of 9.2.11.v20150529 in a jetty version tag with 9.3.11.v20160721, and all the Maven Dependencies get updated. No other change is made. After that, the application stops working with the details below.

The complete log from the **first**, successful run, with Jetty 9.**2**.11 is

```
2016-08-22 18:24:29.079:INFO::main: Logging initialized @272ms
2016-08-22 18:24:29.222:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.11.v20150529
2016-08-22 18:24:29.630:WARN:oeja.AnnotationConfiguration:main: ServletContainerInitializers: detected. Class hierarchy: empty
2016-08-22 18:24:29.755:WARN:oaj.EmbeddedServletOptions:main: Warning: Invalid value for the initParam keepgenerated. Will use the default value of "false"
2016-08-22 18:24:29.756:WARN:oaj.EmbeddedServletOptions:main: Warning: Invalid value for the initParam fork. Will use the default value of "true"
2016-08-22 18:24:29.787:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@66048bfd{/jetty-jsp-example,file:/F:/JettyTutorials/jetty-jsp-example/src/main/webapp/,AVAILABLE}
2016-08-22 18:24:29.890:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@5e2134c1{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2016-08-22 18:24:29.891:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @1088ms
```

The log from the **second**, failing run, with Jetty 9.**3**.11, starts like this:

```
2016-08-22 18:25:52.551:INFO::main: Logging initialized @297ms
2016-08-22 18:25:52.827:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.3.11.v20160721
2016-08-22 18:25:53.260:INFO:oeja.AnnotationConfiguration:main: Scanning elapsed time=0ms
2016-08-22 18:25:53.300:WARN:oatud.DigesterFactory:main: The XML schema [XMLSchema.dtd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
```

The last message line then goes on for 24 more lines with all kinds of dtd-s and xsd-s, followed by a stack dump starting by

```
2016-08-22 18:25:53.358:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@5abca1e0{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/jasper/JasperException
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:113)
```

and further down

```
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
    :
    :
```

I am not familiar enough with this complete setup to see what the problem is, I can't find a contact information where I found the example, and I cannot find any guidance when searching the web, possibly in part because I can't see what to search for, so I am reaching out to this community, hoping for some guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044628/spring-error-during-build):

> The relevant part of the error message is:
>
> invalid LOC header (bad signature)
>   which suggests some binary file being broken, most likely one of the dependencies. If you have a fast Internet connection, just delete your whole maven repository and let maven redownload all the dependencies:
>
> rm -rf ~/.m2/repository/*

Or, on my Windows 10: I exited Eclipse, deleted C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository, restarted Eclipse. After a while, most of the configuration was reloaded, but I had to save the pom file again to have the whole thing rebuilt. Then it worked! Thank you SO.