# Tomcat 9.0 server can't start

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm having a problem with my Tomcat 9.0 on Eclipse Neon where it doesn't want to start and this comes out. I've tried to search for the answers online but i still don't find it.

```
Sep 19, 2016 10:47:08 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:BankSinarmas' did not find a matching property.
Sep 19, 2016 10:47:08 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Dompetku' did not find a matching property.
Sep 19, 2016 10:47:08 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M9
Sep 19, 2016 10:47:08 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Jul 4 2016 18:22:47 UTC
Sep 19, 2016 10:47:08 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         9.0.0.0
Sep 19, 2016 10:47:08 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
Sep 19, 2016 10:47:08 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.0
Sep 19, 2016 10:47:08 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Sep 19, 2016 10:47:08 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_102
Sep 19, 2016 10:47:08 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_102-b14
Sep 19, 2016 10:47:08 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Sep 19, 2016 10:47:08 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\User\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp4
Sep 19, 2016 10:47:08 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
Sep 19, 2016 10:47:08 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\User\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp4
Sep 19, 2016 10:47:08 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
Sep 19, 2016 10:47:08 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\User\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp4\wtpwebapps
Sep 19, 2016 10:47:08 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\endorsed
Sep 19, 2016 10:47:08 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Sep 19, 2016 10:47:08 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_102\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_102/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_102/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_102/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\adb;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files(86)\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-7.0.69;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0;C:\Users\User\Desktop;;.
Sep 19, 2016 10:47:09 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8071"]
Sep 19, 2016 10:47:09 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Sep 19, 2016 10:47:09 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8072"]
Sep 19, 2016 10:47:09 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Sep 19, 2016 10:47:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1459 ms
Sep 19, 2016 10:47:09 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Sep 19, 2016 10:47:09 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M9
Sep 19, 2016 10:47:09 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Dompetku]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:911)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:890)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1403)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Dompetku]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@2ee701ba]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4830)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4962)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@7b90cfad]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet.initInternal(JarResourceSet.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.IOUtils.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet.initInternal(JarResourceSet.java:137)
    ... 13 more

Sep 19, 2016 10:47:09 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/BankSinarmas]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:911)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:890)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1403)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/BankSinarmas]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@294d4e02]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4830)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4962)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@5a68b72a]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet.initInternal(JarResourceSet.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.IOUtils.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet.initInternal(JarResourceSet.java:137)
    ... 13 more

Sep 19, 2016 10:47:09 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:911)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:655)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1403)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:920)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:890)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    ... 6 more

Sep 19, 2016 10:47:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8070]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:655)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:920)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    ... 11 more

Sep 19, 2016 10:47:09 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8071"]
Sep 19, 2016 10:47:09 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8072"]
Sep 19, 2016 10:47:09 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Sep 19, 2016 10:47:09 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8071"]
Sep 19, 2016 10:47:09 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8072"]
```

Is there any fix on this? Thanks before

Comment: Looks like a corrupted installation. Reinstall Tomcat.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292103/some-error-while-running-spring-mvc-project suggests that you may have corrupt jar files in your class path. The relevant part of the traceback appears to be `java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)`

Comment: I've reinstall Tomcat, and it still shows the error.

Comment: Thankyou Seth, i'll try that

Comment: It works well, thank you guys